# How to align-items: center AND align-self: stretch?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an element I'd like to be (cross-axis) centered but also 'grow' to a nominal size even with too-little content, BUT ALSO 'shrink' when the width of the page becomes smaller than 350px wide.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

  .child {
    max-width: 350px; 
    align-self: stretch;
  }
}
```

Adding `align-self: stretch;` to `.child` does the job of making it 350px wide, but it seems to negate the `align-items: center;` in `.parent`

Is there a way to do this in CSS that I'm missing? Please note that the element can't just be 350px wide all the time - it must also respond to horizontal page resizing as it does in the example fiddle.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1uqpxn8L/1/

Comment: Can you use media queries?

Comment: @SmokeyDawson - Sure, but I'd like to keep it as 'natural' as possible. I can also add some dummy child divs to artificially center the main child, but it seems hacky to do stuff like that. I'm hoping for a 'native' flexbox answer if possible.

Comment: check my answer - probably the mot natural way of doing it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I think you should use `justify-content` to h-align child to center.

Please note, when you apply `display: flex` property to parent, you should apply `flex` property to child.

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent .child {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I should be 350px wide
    <br> and centered in the yellow
    <br> unless the page gets smaller,
    <br> in which case I should have
    <br> 10px padding on either side.
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see the result here, hope this is what you mean: https://jsfiddle.net/1uqpxn8L/11/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you removed the flex-direction which fundamentally changes the layout from column (cross-axis sizing) to row (normal flex sizing). I need this to work for cross-axis as there are other elements that need to be in the same column.

Comment: You solved it! I updated your answer so I can accept it - there was some leftover stuff from your first answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  .child {
    width: 350px;
    @media(max-width: 350px) {
       width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media(max-width: 350px) {
  .child { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

So whats happening is I'm using a media query to change the width of the child depending on the width of the browser.

Comment: Not bad! I'll fall back on this if there isn't a 'native' way to do it.

Comment: After some testing, the problem with this is that I lose the 10px margin on the sides, even if I 're-add' it in the query. Unfortunately I can't choose a size like 90% because it won't work with my application. UPDATE: I suppose a calculated width MIGHT work, but it's just another layer of complexity and maintenance. Here's an updated fiddle using your idea that does exactly what I want but requires some gymnastics: https://jsfiddle.net/1uqpxn8L/2/

Comment: @MarkChapel did you add the padding of 10px on the parent component like I have done in my question? This will solve your problem no need to use `calc()`

Comment: Haha crap! No, I didn't. I must be getting tired. Thanks!

Comment: I'd still love to find a way to do this without media queries, but if I can't figure out a better way I certainly will :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the **flex-direction property**. Then it's working as you expected. But there will be a problem if you want to display children elements as column manner. The shrinking problem occurs with the **flex-direction** property or **flex-flow:column** values as I checked.

Comment: Yes I need it to work in the cross-axis (column) direction. Thank you for looking though!